# Extrude only one face using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

There is a subdivided cube (4x4x4 vertices).

[image]

I only need to extrude one of his faces, such as the middle one on either side using geometry nodes.
But when I try to specify a vertex group, all planes touching these vertices are extruded.

[image]

[image]

The result should be as follows(Using geometry nodes):

[image]

I need to be able to extrude not only middle face, but any I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extrude a specific face in *Geometry Nodes* by selecting it.

The selection can be achieved by comparing the current index with a value of your choice. Of course you have to know this index or find it out by trial and error.

There are several index viewers that allow you to view the index of the faces.

> This question has also been asked here before: [How to show index of faces, lines, points?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273640)

[image]

An alternative would also be the selection via a vertex group (**Blender 3.2+**):

[image]

Comment: Utilities > Compare node (Integer, Equal) ... or Utilities > Math node (Compare, Epsilon 0)

Comment: @vklidu Thanks for the complementary information!

Comment: but how does one know what index is needed for the desired face?

Comment: @rothloup I have updated the question accordingly, and hope this helps you.

Comment: It helps me understand, but doesn't help me solve the issue - there is no way to know what index the relevant face unless it's for a specific case.  Thank you.

Comment: @rothloup After all, the question here is *"How can I extrude only one face using geometry nodes?"*, and this answer here is the solution. If this one doesn't help you, please create a new question so we can think about your specific task.

Comment: of course.  not criticizing.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to extrude using a Weight map:

[image: Extruding weight paint]

Geometry Nodes:

[image: Geometry Nodes]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Capture Attribute` node to transfer the vertex group information to the face corners:

[image]