# How to show index of faces,lines,points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a model and want to change the color of one face in Geometry Nodes, but it's hard to find the right index of the face, unless I search it one by one.Is there an easy way(built-in is best) to show all index on the screen?
The result looks like this.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately there is no built-in solution AFAIK, but different people built index viewer for GN like here: https://artofriaz3d.gumroad.com/l/indexviewerfields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### EDIT 2

I've made a small, free addon for this functionality. It can be found at https://psyonic.gumroad.com/l/GN_Indices_Viewer

### EDIT

From the comments, the original answer would not work for Geometry nodes, Can you please try this and let me know if it works for you

In the scripting tab, create a new script and paste the following in:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

depsgraph = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eval_mesh = context.view_layer.objects.active.evaluated_get(depsgraph).data.copy()
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("evel_obj", eval_mesh)
coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
coll.objects.link(obj)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
```

In preferences, turn on "Developer Extras"

[image]

Then in the Viewport Overlays menu turn on "Indices"

[image]

This will show the indices of any selected items in edit mode.

With your object selected run the script (little play button in the scripting tab)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138962/discussion-on-answer-by-psyonic-how-to-show-index-of-faces-lines-points).